# How to name variables in JSON. With the sign '_' or without?

Tags: java, json, spring

I wonder how to professionally call variables in JSON and what does it matter. For example, in this [StackExchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), separate words in one variable are separated by a sign `_`, while in another code, for example, the Netflix project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Netflix/genie/blob/master/genie-common/src/main/java/com/netflix/genie/common/dto/search/JobSearchResult.java) does not have this character anymore, and for a simple one string. So what is the meaning of using `_` in a variable in JSON?

Comment: Naming conventions are just that, conventions. Various programming languages promote various schemes. There is no right or wrong, as long as you don't break the relevant syntax. The only key is, pick a scheme, and **be consistent**

Answer (score 0):

This is again topic where people can debate about their preferences.I think people from perl, ruby background prefer underscore while other people prefer camelCase. You can use whatever you prefer and just make sure to be consistent with what you choose. I personally  follow [google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml) guide which uses camelCase.